# How can I automate modifying key/value pairs in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, find-and-replace

I often want to automate this sort of task in a shell script:

if the line:

`SOMEKEY=SOMEVALUE`

exists in a file, then change it to

`SOMEKEY=SOMEOTHERVALUE`

otherwise, append the line `SOMEKEY=SOMEOTHERVALUE` in the file.

How could I go about this?  I think I could do it using a combination of `grep` and `sed`, but I'm sure it's a common enough task that someone has already worked out an elegant solution.

By the way, when replacing I would normally do something like this

`sed -i 's/old/new/g' fname`

But it means I have to be very careful when composing my regular expressions, so as not to make a mistake.  Is there an easy way to "preview" what changes which would occur from my call to `sed` without actually stomping on the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use awk for this task:

```
   awk -F'=' -v "keyname=$SOMEKEY" -v "value=$SOMEOTHERVALUE" '
            $1 == keyname {
                    if ($2 != value) $2 = "\"" value "\""
                    key_found = 1
            }

            { print $1 "=" $2 }

            END { if (!key_found) print keyname "=\"" value "\"" }
   ' fname
```

assuming

```
 SOMEKEY=key1
 SOMEOTHERVALUE="John Doe is dead!"
```

and given this input:

```
 key1="John Doe is geat!
 key2="Who's John Wayne?"
```

One gets:

```
 key1="John Doe is dead!"
 key2="Who's John Wayne?"
```

Or if no `key1` line is present, `key1="John Doe is dead!"` will be appended at the end.

**Note:** On Solaris or other UNIX derivates that still ship an old version of *awk(1)*, *nawk(1)* should be used instead.

Comment: Missed that last question: If you just want to preview your changes, omit the option `-i` and code: *yoursedcommand* `|grep fname -` That will compare the outcome of your command with the original file `fname`

Comment: i tried, for example, `sed 's/HISTSIZE/SPAM/g' ~/.bashrc | grep ~/.bashrc` but didn't see any output.

Comment: So sorry - stupid typo (obviously I was thinking about something else...) Correct is: *yoursedcmd* `| diff fname - `

Comment: yes i thought you might have meant `diff`, but when i tried that i get `diff: missing operand after `/home/wim/.bashrc'`

Comment: Don't forget the second argument to *diff*: it's only a single minus sign (`-`) which indicates that the 2nd file for comparison shall be read from *stdin*